# finding probability from a kernel density estimate in R

Tags: r, kernel, probability-density

Using the `density(dataset)` function in R to derive the underlying data distribution. On `plot(density(dataset))`, I get the distribution of my dataset with density estimate along y-axis and the observed dataset along x-axis.

Using this density estimate, I want to find the probability of occurrence of a new observed variable (i.e., exactly at `x` where `x` lies within `Xmax` and `Xmin` as observed in the training dataset). Is there a way of estimating the probability from the kernel density estimate?

Earlier I thought of finding the y-axis value from the density estimate plot corresponding to the desired x. But later, I realized its not the right way. Kindly provide your suggestions. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should look at the help page for ?density and in particular the Value section. As far as probability is concerned, I created a density object named rrd and notice that: `sum(rrd$y[-1]*diff(rrd$x))`
[1] 1.000844

Comment: @BondedDust Value section under density help papge doesnt explain the way of finding the probability of occurence at a given point from a given density estimate. I am specifically looking to estimate the probability, having a prior kernel density estimate. Appreciate your concern

Comment: Well, it's unlikely that they will ever explain how to do what you ask for since the _probability_ at any given point is exactly 0 (unless of course you are working with a Dirac function).  Post some code and data and you can keep this question from being just a statistics lesson.